# Quartz Scheduling to delete files

Tags: cron, apache-camel, quartz-scheduler

I am using the file component with an argument quartz scheduler in order to pull some files from a given directory on every hour. Then i transform the data from the files and move the content to other files in other directory. After that I am moving the input files to an archive directory. When a file is moved to this directory it should stay there only a week and then it should be deleted automatically. The problem is that Im not really sure how can i start a new cron job because I dont really know when any of the files is moved to that archive directory. Maybe is something really trivial but I am pretty new to camel and I dont know the solution. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

> Use option "filterFile"

Every file has modified timestamp and you can use this timestamp to filter file that are older than 1 week. Under [file component](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html), there exist an option `filterFile`

```
filterFile=${date:file:yyyyMMdd}<${date:now-7d:yyyyMMdd}
```

Above evaluation comes from [file language](http://camel.apache.org/file-language.html), `${date:file:yyyyMMdd}` denote modified timestamp of the file in form (year)(month)(day) and `${date:now-7d:yyyyMMdd}` denote current time minus 7 days in form (year)(month)(day).

Comment: Hi @hk6279. Thank you for the answer! Im quite sure thats the right approach but unfortunately I am getting a RuntimeException:

`due to: expected symbol whiteSpace but was functionStart at location 22
${date:file:yyyyMMdd}<${date:now-7d:yyyyMMdd}
                      *` 

The asterics symbol is below the second $ sign

Comment: @Angel Maybe you can try `${date:file:yyyyMMdd} < ${date:now-7d:yyyyMMdd}`